# Positioning UIElement in Custom Control

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, uielement, wpf-positioning

I am developing a Custom Control, where there is a `TextBox` and a `Button` placed inside the `Grid`.

The thing is when I set a Custom Property for the `UserControl` Say - Left : the Button should be displayed before the `TextBox`, and for Right the Button should be displayed on the right side of the text box.

Since, I am defining both the elements in a `Grid` - am not able to position as per my requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to use a `Grid`, You can make your `Grid` have 3 columns and switch the `TextBox` `Grid.Column` based on your custom property.

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Button Grid.Column="1"
          Content="Some Text" />
  <TextBox Text="Test">
    <TextBox.Style>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Grid.Column"
                Value="0" />
        <Style.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                                                        AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},
                                          Path=Left}"
                        Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Grid.Column"
                    Value="2" />
          </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
  </TextBox>
</Grid>
```

you can switch the `{x:Type UserControl}` in the `DataTrigger` to your `{x:Type CustomUserControl}`